# Created() is not executing after delete. Inertia + Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, inertiajs

I'm new with Vuejs and Inertia. I've created a simple dashboard using both and Laravel.
Everything works well except after delete an element, created() is not executing. Surely I'm making a mistake, but I don't found it.

Example:
Initial page:
[image: Initial page]

If I press 'editar', I can edit the value.
I edit first value, 17 to 18.
[image: Edit page]

[image: Value updated]

And this works well. But if I want to delete the first element. The table is updated, because it depends from a prop (elements), but the elements below depend with created().

After removing:
[image: Removing element]

Index.vue

```
<div class="mb-6 bg-white rounded-md shadow" v-if="elementsFiltrats[0].elements.length != 0">
  <h2 class="pressupost_gastos_h2">General</h2>

  <ul class="pressupost_gastos_ul">
     <li v-for="e in elementsFiltrats[0].elements" :key="e.id" class="hover:bg-gray-100 focus-within:bg-gray-100 pressupost_gastos_li">
      {{e.nom}} - {{e.valor.toFixed(2)}}€
     </li>
  </ul>

  <h3 class="pressupost_gastos_h3">Total: {{elementsFiltrats[0].valor_total.toFixed(2)}}€ (+10%) = {{(elementsFiltrats[0].valor_total*1.10).toFixed(2)}}€</h3>
</div>

export default {
  metaInfo: { title: 'Presupuestos' },
  components: {
    Icon,
    Pagination,
    SearchFilter,
  },
  layout: Layout,
  props: {
    filters: Object,
    exercici: Object,
    elements: Array,
    comunitat: Object,
    elementsagrupats: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        search: this.filters.search
      },
      elementsFiltrats: []
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.splitByType()
  },
  watch: {
    form: {
      deep: true,
      handler: throttle(function() {
        this.$inertia.get(this.route('pressuposts', this.exercici.id), pickBy(this.form), { preserveState: true })
      }, 150),
    },
    '$route' : 'splitByType'
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.form = mapValues(this.form, () => null)
    },
    destroy(idExercici, idPressupost) {
      if (confirm("Seguro que quieres eliminar el elemento del presupuesto?")) {
        this.$inertia.delete(this.route('pressuposts.destroy', [idExercici, idPressupost]))
      }
    },
    edit(idExercici, idPressupost) {
      this.$inertia.get(this.route('pressuposts.edit', [idExercici, idPressupost]))
    },
    splitByType(){
      console.log("hola")
      // 0 general
      // 1 escales
      // 2 garatge
      // valor_total
      var elem = [
        {
          'elements' : [],
          'valor_total': 0
        }, 
        {
          'elements' : [],
          'valor_total': 0
        }, 
        {
          'elements' : [],
          'valor_total': 0
        }
      ];

      this.elementsagrupats.forEach(element => {
        var pos = 0;
        if(element.casella === 'general'){
          pos = 0;
        }else if(element.casella === 'escales'){
          pos = 1;
        }else{
          pos = 2;
        }

        elem[pos].elements.push({
          'nom' : element['nom'],
          'valor' : element['valor_total']
        });
        elem[pos].valor_total += element.valor_total;
      });

      this.elementsFiltrats =  elem;

    }

  },
}
```

Controller:

Update method has:

Update code...

```
return Redirect::route('pressuposts', $exercici->id)->with('success', 'Element actualitzat.');
```

Destroy method has:

Delete code...

```
return Redirect::route('pressuposts', $exercici->id)->with('success', 'Element eliminat.');
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You want to synchronize data between components, which are independent of each other - [Vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) would be an idea. Otherwise you will have to manually `$emit` every state change.

Comment: I've created a watch to solve it. Maybe it's not best choice, but it works